# Why would DmlOptions EmailHeader not work for Event Creation with email notifications?

Tags: apex, event, dmloptions

I have a code sample as below:

```
Database.DMLOptions dmlo    = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
database.insert( this.myNewEventsWithEmail, dmlo );
system.debug('@@ Create Events (With EMAIL) : ['+myNewEventsWithEmail.size() + '] ( '+dmlo+' )');
```

where `this.myNewEventsWithEmail` is list of **Event** sObjects.

My debug log says that this code was executed and with correct EmailHeader option:

```
02:49:32.033 (1033993374)|USER_DEBUG|[430]|DEBUG|@@ Create Events (With EMAIL) : [2] ( DMLOptions:[AllowFieldTruncation=null, AssignmentRuleHeader=AssignmentRuleHeader:[AssignmentRuleId=null, UseDefaultRule=null], DuplicateRuleHeader=DuplicateRuleHeader:[AllowSave=null], EmailHeader=EmailHeader:[TriggerAutoResponseEmail=null, TriggerOtherEmail=null, TriggerUserEmail=true], LocaleOptions=null, LocalizeErrors=null, OptAllOrNone=null] )
```

I have verified that `triggerUserEmail` is set to `True` but still **`No Email is being sent`** to the user who is assigned the Event.

Weird thing is, same code works just fine with list of **Task** object records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Varun, I don't think that Salesforce sends notification emails to an internal user when a new Event is created that is assigned to that user. This functionality only exists for Tasks.

To verify this for yourself, try using the standard Salesforce UI to create a new Event record assigned to a user other than yourself, and see if Salesforce sends you an email --- it won't. (Go to /00U/e to create a new Event, /00T/e to create a new Task)

Comment: weird, I didn't realized that, thnx for pointing it out.